# Test for compairing data on same days in a week in different years

Tags: statistical-power, systematic

So I'm doing some power system analysis on active and reactive power loads and I'd like to compare the data from 2015 and data from 2015 to see how much they differ. The nature of the load is such that on same days in a week we have more or less a same load so I'd like to see how much does the load differ on let's say 8th of September 2015 and on 9th of September 2014, so on a Tuesday.

What thest could I use for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have some kind of seasonality in your data, you might want to try seasonal adjustment programs. X-13ARIMA-SEATS can be a really powerful tool in this respect.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I have seasonality in my data and I would like to see whether there is an improvement after introducing new methods of control. You still suggest me to use X-13ARIMA-SEATS or there is a simpler method?

Comment: X-13ARIMA-SEATS is a very massive program, I agree, but also a very good one. In your case it should not be too complicated to seasonally adjust your data. Census Bureau offers the program written in Fortan (I think), which you can download for free. Additionally there exists a quite decent rPackage using the Census program.